# getDeviceId() API always returns null value on android emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator

why does it return null value?
is there a way for assigning a device's id to each an emulator.

Comment: Maybe if you made a custom image.

Comment: deviceid is something like IMEI number for mobiles.. your emulator is a virtual device not a real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is performing as expected, as the emulator does not have an IMEI number.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()

If you test for `null`, you can return your own fake device id for testing purposes.